# How to reduce useing of memory when I use Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, memory

I need to check data from server. I make Ajax query every 15 seconds. But after some hours my memory is overflowed.
I tried it in Opera, Firefox and Chrome, everywhere particular result

```js
setTimeout(function timer() {
    Check();
    setTimeout(timer, 10000);
}, 10000);

function Check() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://example/server/NEWS.php',
        type: "POST",
        catch: false,
        success: (data) => {
            CheckNews(data);
        }
    });
}

function CheckNews(data) {
    if (data == 'Try again') document.location.reload();
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    data.forEach(function (item, i, arr) {
        switch (item[0]) {
            case "Del": //Delete
                  console.log('Del);
                break;
            case 'Add': //Add
                console.log('Add ');
                break;

            case 'NewM':
                break;
            default:
        }
    });
    data = null;
}
```

Comment: This assumption was substantiated by an analysis with a memory profiler, whereby the shown script was identified as the cause?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the most about jQuery, but you could probably delete the data after x amount of time.

Also, you have an error in your code at the delete part. You forgot to put a closing `'`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is setInterval. You're calling setTimeout over and over again, and each function call is left on the stack because it's technically not finished. I think that's why you're having memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `setInterval` function instead of `setTimeout` function for your repeated call. `setInterval` function is optimised for repeated calls and will call the callback function(passed as the first parameter) after the specified time duration(passed as the second parameter) repeatedly until you clear the interval using `clearInterval` function. So, you can replace your `setTimeout` function with:

```
setInterval(function() {
  Check();
}, 10000);
```